# Create Table in Gimp

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to create a table in Gimp?

Something like this for example:
[image]

I made this with one single field which I duplicated many times to arrange it at the specific points and want to create more tables with ***x*** rows and ***y*** columns

By the way I am using Gimp 2.8.10

-Edit:
I know that you can import tables made with word etc. but it has to be created in Gimp because I need the Cells to be individual Layers (sorry did not mention this in first post)

-Edit:
As mentioned before I need the cells to be separate layers, is there a way to achieve this for a grid of ***x*** rows and ***y*** columns? Except creating the layers manually.

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote?

Comment: Question shows no effort

Comment: The grid plugin does the job to create a table, but it doesnt create a layer for each of the cells

Comment: Please reference the link above your question that has marked this as duplicate.  I believe it may help you but if Im wrong and it doesn't help feel free to edit your post and we can re-open it for you.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the pointed to question - this wants each cell in a separate layer - which can't be achieved with the grid rendering plug-in.

Comment: @jsbueno that would be up to the OP.  If the OP didnt make an [edit] to their question then we are to assume that the question linked did in fact answer it.  If you are need assistance to something similar you are more than welcome to create a new question and link back to these.